# Wrong output by query in ms sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have written a query in ms sql server in which I am using pivoting. As I am not familiar with pivoting I want to know where I am going wrong, as my query is not producing the desired output. My query is like this:

```
SELECT Name,ap,er,ft,vp
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tbStudent.Name,
                        dbo.tbSubjects.SubCode,
                        dbo.fnTotalDays(dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID,
                                        dbo.tbStudent.StudentID) AS Total 
          FROM dbo.tbAttendance
               INNER JOIN dbo.tbAttendanceMaster
                 ON dbo.tbAttendance.MasterAID = dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.AtdID
               INNER JOIN dbo.tbStudent
                 ON dbo.tbAttendance.StID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID
               INNER JOIN dbo.tbSubjects
                 ON dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID = dbo.tbSubjects.SubID
               LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbSemester
                 ON dbo.tbSubjects.SemID = dbo.tbSemester.SemID) sq
 PIVOT(sum(Total) FOR SubCode IN(ap,er,ft,vp) ) AS pt
UNION ALL
SELECT Name ,ap ,er ,ft ,vp
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT tbStudent.Name,
                        dbo.tbSubjects.SubCode,
                        dbo.fnNoOfDays(dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID,
                                       dbo.tbStudent.StudentID) AS Present
          FROM dbo.tbAttendance
               INNER JOIN dbo.tbAttendanceMaster
                 ON dbo.tbAttendance.MasterAID = dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.AtdID
               INNER JOIN dbo.tbStudent
                 ON dbo.tbAttendance.StID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID
               INNER JOIN dbo.tbSubjects
                 ON dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID = dbo.tbSubjects.SubID
               LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbSemester
                 ON dbo.tbSubjects.SemID = dbo.tbSemester.SemID ) sq2
 PIVOT(sum(Present) FOR SubCode IN(ap,er,ft,vp) ) AS pt2
```

It is giving me output like this:

```
Name    Ep  ER  FT  SQ       
Amir    2   9   3   2         
muzamil NULL    5   NULL     
roof    2   9   3   7        
Amir    0   9   3   1
muzamil NULL    5   NULL     
roof    2   7   3   7
```

but I want output like this:

```
Name    Ep  ER  FT  SQ          JB   CQ  LQ   YC
Amir    2   9   3   2           0    9   3    1
muzamil NULL    5   NULL        NULL 5   NULL NULL
roof    2   9   3   7           2    7   3    7
```

I want the last three rows which are the output of second query to show as the new columns JB, CQ, LQ and YC on the original three rows as shown in my table above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be some mismatches in the column names in your query, you use `SELECT Name,ap,er,ft,vp` but the sample output lists `Name    Ep  ER  FT  SQ`, so you might have to adjust the answer below to fit your needs.

I think this query might work:

```
SELECT 
    Name, 
    MAX(ap) AS EP, MAX(er) AS ER, 
    MAX(ft) AS FT, MAX(vp) AS SQ, 
    MAX(jb) AS JB, MAX(cq) AS CQ, 
    MAX(lq) AS LQ, MAX(yc) AS YC 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Name, 
        ap, er, ft, vp, 
        NULL AS JB, NULL AS CQ, NULL AS LQ, NULL AS YC 
    FROM (
         SELECT DISTINCT 
            tbStudent.Name,
            dbo.tbSubjects.SubCode,
            dbo.fnTotalDays(dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID, 
                            dbo.tbStudent.StudentID) AS Total 
         FROM dbo.tbAttendance
         INNER JOIN dbo.tbAttendanceMaster
           ON dbo.tbAttendance.MasterAID = dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.AtdID
         INNER JOIN dbo.tbStudent
           ON dbo.tbAttendance.StID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID
         INNER JOIN dbo.tbSubjects
           ON dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID = dbo.tbSubjects.SubID
         LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbSemester
           ON dbo.tbSubjects.SemID = dbo.tbSemester.SemID
         ) sq
    PIVOT(SUM(Total) FOR SubCode IN (ap,er,ft,vp) 
        ) AS pt

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        Name, 
        NULL AS ap, NULL AS er, NULL AS ft, NULL AS vp, 
        ap AS JB, er AS CQ, ft AS LQ, vp AS YC 
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT tbStudent.Name,
                        dbo.tbSubjects.SubCode,
                        dbo.fnNoOfDays(dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID,
                                       dbo.tbStudent.StudentID) AS Present
        FROM dbo.tbAttendance
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbAttendanceMaster
          ON dbo.tbAttendance.MasterAID = dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.AtdID
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbStudent
          ON dbo.tbAttendance.StID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID
        INNER JOIN dbo.tbSubjects
          ON dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID = dbo.tbSubjects.SubID
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tbSemester
          ON dbo.tbSubjects.SemID = dbo.tbSemester.SemID 
        ) sq2
    PIVOT(SUM(Present) FOR SubCode IN (ap,er,ft,vp) 
        ) AS pt2
    ) AS subquery GROUP BY Name
```